# why is my Keras Siamese network gives issue on sample size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So basically I copied the whole keras example for Siamese network from here https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/

But I have changed a few things mainly the create pair function.

```
def create_pairs(datapath, directories):
    pairs = []
    labels = []
    for file in os.listdir(datapath):
        file_path = datapath + file
        for pic in os.listdir(file_path):
            # Get positive pair
            file_choice = None
            while file_choice is None:
                file_choice = get_random_pic(file_path, pic)
            #print(file_choice)
            p1_path = file_path +"/"+ pic
            p2_path = file_path +"/"+ file_choice
            #print("File: {} Pic1: {} Rand:{}".format(file,p1_path,p2_path))        
            # Get negative pair from a random directory
            rand_dir = None
            while rand_dir is None:
                rand_dir = get_random_dir(directories, file_path)
            #print("CP:{} RD:{}".format(file_path, rand_dir))
            rand_pic = random.choice(os.listdir(rand_dir))
            # Negative example
            p3_path = rand_dir +"/"+ rand_pic
            #print("P1", p1_path)
            #print("P2",p2_path)
            #print("P3",p3_path)
            # Read in all the file using cv2
            a = cv2.imread(p1_path)
            p = cv2.imread(p2_path)
            n = cv2.imread(p3_path)
            pos_pair = [a, p]
            neg_pair = [a,n]

            # Now create paris
            #pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]

            pairs.append(pos_pair)
            labels.append(1)
            pairs.append(neg_pair)
            labels.append(0)
return np.array(pairs), np.array(labels)
```

This is my method for reading in images from a folder which is split up by person or category.

I create the data set like this
`X, labels = create_pairs(datapath, directories)`

This gives me a train and test set like this

```
Train sample : data:1000 label:1000
Test sample : data:920 label:920
(1000, 2, 160, 60, 3)
(920, 2, 160, 60, 3)
```

My input shape for the base network is 
    (2, 160, 60, 3)
This is the overall input shapes

```
print("Train Shape: {} label:{}".format(x_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print("Test Shape: {} label:{}".format(x_test.shape, y_test.shape))
print(input_a.shape)
print(input_shape)
Train Shape: (1000, 2, 160, 60, 3) label:(1000,)
Test Shape: (920, 2, 160, 60, 3) label:(920,)
(?, 2, 160, 60, 3)
(2, 160, 60, 3)
```

And this is my model fit method

```
model.fit([x_train[:0],x_train[:1]], y_train,
      batch_size=128,
      epochs=epochs,
      validation_data=([x_test[:1], x_test[:1]], y_test))
```

From the example it should work fine as it looks the same as the example - msint data.

But it gives me this error:

> All input arrays (`x`) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: `[(0, 2, 160, 60, 3), (1, 2, 160, 60, 3)]`

**********************New Stuff added after here*******************************
So i got it working, but I dont know if it is learning the right stuff.

```
history = model.fit([x_train, x_train], y_train,
      batch_size=128,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose = 1,
      validation_data=([x_test, x_test], y_test))
```

this is how I am doing it, but it does not look like how the example is set up. Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Should the line `model.fit([x_train[:0],x_train[:1]]` be `model.fit([x_train[:1],x_train[:1]]` instead? It's just a typo :)

Comment: It gives this issue:

Comment: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 1000 target samples.

Comment: Yep, it's because you should also pass only one target vector `model.fit([x_train[:1],x_train[:1]], y_train[:1], ...`. The same applies to the validation data `y_test[:1]`.

Comment: That kind of worked as it starts training, but it gives me this message Train on 1 samples, validate on 1 samples. It should have 1000 samples to train on

Comment: I thought you just wanted to test if everything works and that's why you're passing only one training sample. If you wanna train on the whole dataset, then just don't slice your arrays and pass `x_train`  and `y_train` to the `model.fit` call.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me
 Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:

Comment: I think how Keras set it up it needs an array of two images as the input of the model

Comment: model = Model([input_a, input_b], distance)

Comment: Thank you @constt you helped me out a lot and got me on the right track of thinking. I was trying to keep it close to the example one and that is what messed me up

Comment: No problem, glad it finally has worked out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way around the issues.
So the new model fit is similar to what constt stated like this :

```
history = model.fit([a_train, c_train], y_train,
      batch_size=128,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose = 1,
      validation_data=([a_test, c_test], y_test))
```

The big change I made was to the pair creation. 
I basically made two arrays the Anchor array and the compare array. This is the final code for the return statement.

```
 anchor.append(a)
        anchor.append(a)
        comp.append(p)
        comp.append(n)
        labels.append(1)
        labels.append(0)


        #pos_pair = [a, p]
        #neg_pair = [a,n]

        # Now create paris
        #pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
        #pairs += [[a,p]]
        #pairs += [[a,n]]
        #labels += [1,0]
        #pairs.append(pos_pair)
        #labels.append(1)
        #pairs.append(neg_pair)
        #labels.append(0)


return np.array(anchor), np.array(comp), np.array(labels)
```